# What is relationship count condition in WhereHas Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am having a difficulty understanding the relationship count condition in [WhereHas](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations). The docs page does not have discussion about it but [API page](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereHas) talks about it. Quote from API.

> Builder|Builder whereHas(string $relation, Closure $callback, string
>   $operator = '>=', int $count = 1)
>
> Add a relationship count condition to the query with where clauses.

**Example**

A `Resource` Model has Many to Many relation to `ResourceCategory`

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('ResourceCategory', 'resource_category_mapping');
}
```

**Relationship condition in Has**

The relationship condition in [Has](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_has) is working as expected.

```
Resource::has('categories', '>', 1)->get()
//this return all resources which have more than one catgories
```

**Relationship condition in WhereHas**

The relationship condition in WhereHas is not working as expected. I am sure I have misunderstood it.

```
Resource::whereHas('categories', function ( $query){
            $query->whereIn('resource_category_id', [1, 2, 4]);
        }, '>', 1)->get()
```

The above code should return resources which whose categories belong to either of [1, 2, 4] and the resource has more than one categories. But it is not.

**Question**

Kindly explain the relationship condition in WhereHas, may be providing an example would be much helpful.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Normally, **whereHas()** checks if your model has **at least one** related model. You can set **$count** to some higher value to increase the count to **N**and fetch only the models that have at least **N** related models.

In your case, calling

```
Resource::has('categories', '>', 2)->get();
```

will return only those **Resources** that have **at least 2** related categories.

Comment: can you verify my explanation of my whereHas Code 'The above code should return resources which whose categories belong to either of [1, 2, 4] and the resource has more than one categories'. Is that right...?

Comment: Works for me. Please paste the query you get - replace get() with toSql() - and paste it here.

Comment: select * from `resource` where `resource`.`deleted_at` is null and `first_name` = ? and (select count(*) from `resource_category` inner join `resource_category_mapping` on `resource_category`.`id` = `resource_category_mapping`.`resource_category_id` where `resource_category_mapping`.`resource_id` = `resource`.`id` and `resource_category_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?)) = 3

Comment: Where did that =3 come from? did you add this? The query looks ok apart from this.

Comment: sorry I was just tinkering with code. You can replace it with > 1

Comment: As I said, the query looks ok, are you sure you have correct data? Do you have records that match the above cconditions?

Comment: Oka now i got the point. Its working perfectly fine. Actually i had hard time understanding working of relationship count with WhereHas. I have tested many cases and played for some time with it and now I got the understanding. Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: I was searching for this all day today, thanks it is still helpful after 3 years :)

Comment: This is hanging for me, there are 2K results i wonder if that has something to do with it. this is the kinda solution i am after though